# How are commital proceedings for contempt of court initiated, and who may the process be instigated by?

Tags: england-and-wales, any-jurisdiction, contempt-of-court, committal

An injunction was obtained against Bob for allegedly disrupting/sabotaging the Epsom Derby Jockey Club, prohibiting him from doing such things again in the future. He violated this injunctive prohibition of the court, thereby placing himself in contempt of court, for which he may be subject to committal proceedings.

What process could such proceedings be initiated by, and who would be able to initiate it? Further, what parties would most typically be the ones to instigate it?

Answer (score -1):

### Anyone with standing

Standing requires that the person can or has suffered a genuine harm from the breach of the injunction. For your example, this would be the Epsom Derby Jockey Club. Possibly one or more of its members or guests *might* have standing.

That person would place the matter before the court who may, depending on the evidence, issue an arrest warrant which would be executed by the police.

Comment: I presume the club's officers or president would be representatives/agents of the club

Comment: @Trish what is your point?

Comment: @Seekinganswers they'd be the people that actually are allowed to file on behalf of the club. They act on the standing of the club.

Comment: @Trish the club is a legal person - it files on its own behalf.